# How to fill series data in candle chart in xamarin (TeeChart and MonoTouch)

Tags: xamarin.android, teechart

I am using a tee chart library in xamarin (Android). i am facing a problem to daynamic binding data in "Candle Chart"

The Sample Code Like this!

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.CandleChart);

    //InitializeComponent();

    chart = new Steema.TeeChart.TChart(this.ApplicationContext);
    chart.Zoom.Style = Steema.TeeChart.ZoomStyles.InChart;
    Steema.TeeChart.Themes.BlackIsBackTheme myTheme = new Steema.TeeChart.Themes.BlackIsBackTheme(chart.Chart);
    myTheme.Apply();
    Type tmp = (Type)Steema.TeeChart.Utils.SeriesTypesOf[12];
    Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Series series;
    series = chart.Series.Add(tmp);

    series.FillSampleValues();  /* Here i want to fill series with my data listed bellow */

    chart.Aspect.View3D = Needs3D(chart[0]);
    chart.Panel.Transparent = true;

    SetContentView(chart);
}
```

now i want add series data manually

like :

currentItem.Data.Close

currentItem.Data.Open

currentItem.Data.High

currentItem.Data.Low

currentItem.Time

etc.. so, plz help me to achieve this ..

thanks, in advance

==================================================================================

## My Code Like as Bellow

```
    private void LoadChart(GraphOutput resGraph)
    {
        DataSet_Obj.Tables.Add("CandleTable");
        DataSet_Obj.Tables["CandleTable"].Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Date", System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime")));
        DataSet_Obj.Tables["CandleTable"].Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Open", System.Type.GetType("System.Double")));
        DataSet_Obj.Tables["CandleTable"].Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Close", System.Type.GetType("System.Double")));
        DataSet_Obj.Tables["CandleTable"].Columns.Add(new DataColumn("High", System.Type.GetType("System.Double")));
        DataSet_Obj.Tables["CandleTable"].Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Low", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"))); 

        for (int i = 0; i < resGraph.graphSymbol[0].CandleSticks.Length; i++)
        {
            DataRow_Obj = DataSet_Obj.Tables["CandleTable"].NewRow();
            DataRow_Obj["Date"] = resGraph.graphSymbol[0].CandleSticks[i].CandleTime;        //DateTime 
            DataRow_Obj["Low"] = resGraph.graphSymbol[0].CandleSticks[i].CandleData.Low;     //Float
            DataRow_Obj["Close"] = resGraph.graphSymbol[0].CandleSticks[i].CandleData.Close; //Float
            DataRow_Obj["Open"] = resGraph.graphSymbol[0].CandleSticks[i].CandleData.Open;   //Float
            DataRow_Obj["High"] = resGraph.graphSymbol[0].CandleSticks[i].CandleData.High;   //Float
            DataSet_Obj.Tables["CandleTable"].Rows.Add(DataRow_Obj);
            DataRow_Obj = null;
        }

        Tag_Serie_Candle = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Candle ();
        chart.Series.Add(Tag_Serie_Candle);
        chart.Aspect.View3D = Needs3D(chart[0]);
        chart.Panel.Transparent = true;

        try
        {
            Tag_Serie_Candle.DataSource = DataSet_Obj.Tables["CandleTable"];   /* here I got Error Like: "Cannot bind to non-supported datasource: CandleTable" */
            Tag_Serie_Candle.OpenValues.DataMember = DataSet_Obj.Tables["CandleTable"].Columns["Open"].ToString();
            Tag_Serie_Candle.CloseValues.DataMember = DataSet_Obj.Tables["CandleTable"].Columns["Close"].ToString();
            Tag_Serie_Candle.DateValues.DataMember = DataSet_Obj.Tables["CandleTable"].Columns["Date"].ToString();
            Tag_Serie_Candle.DateValues.DateTime = true;
            Tag_Serie_Candle.HighValues.DataMember = DataSet_Obj.Tables["CandleTable"].Columns["High"].ToString();
            Tag_Serie_Candle.LowValues.DataMember = DataSet_Obj.Tables["CandleTable"].Columns["Low"].ToString();
            Tag_Serie_Candle.LabelMember = "Candle Chart";
            Tag_Serie_Candle.CheckDataSource();

            chartpie.AddView(chart, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent));
        }
        catch (Exception exe)
        {
            exe.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something as in the examples here:

http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=2978&p=10547#p10547
http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=3291&p=11691#p11691
http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=2741&p=11681#p11681

I have found that, at the present moment, this is not working. I added the defect ([ID566](http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=566)) list to be fixed as soon as possible (*now fixed, see update at the bottom of the reply*). If you register at [Steema Software's Bugzilla system](http://bugs.teechart.net/), you will be able to be in the CC List and be notified about status updates. In the meantime you can manually read values from the *DataSet* using this code:

```
Tag_Serie_Candle.DateValues.DateTime = true;

for (int i = 0; i < DataSet_Obj.Tables["CandleTable"].Rows.Count; i++)
{
  DataRow row = DataSet_Obj.Tables["CandleTable"].Rows[i];

  DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(row["Date"]);
  Double open = Convert.ToDouble(row["Open"]);
  Double high = Convert.ToDouble(row["High"]);
  Double low = Convert.ToDouble(row["Low"]);
  Double close = Convert.ToDouble(row["Close"]);

  Tag_Serie_Candle.Add(dt, open, high, low, close);
}
```

**UPDATE:** As of 11th February 2014, [the defect](http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=566) has been fixed. Anyone interested in testing the solution please let me know.

Comment: Still there is some problem to bind data. i am getting error like "Cannot bind to non-supported datasource: CandleTable" ... see the updated code and please help me...

Comment: @Hari which is the type of CandleTable? Can you please send us a simple example project, with a runtime created datasource, so that we can reproduce the problem here? You'll find an example on how to do that here: http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?t=8206. You can post your files at www.steema.net/upload/. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Calvet : i was uploaded a code on "www.steema.net/upload/" so please see the code and inform me,where is i am wrong ..so, please help me to correct it

Comment: @Hari thanks for the example. Looks like this is a bug. I updated my reply with more info and a workaround suggestion.

Comment: @Hari this bug (http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=566) has just been fixed for the next maintenance release. In the meantime, if you are interested, I can provide a test assembly.

Comment: @Hari a maintenance release with this bug fixed was released yesterday: http://www.steema.com/entry/217/TeeChart_for_Xamarin.Android_4.14.6.25_maintenance_release_available